# How do you implement a "Micropayment Channel" in a Dapp?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, dapps

I've come acrossed an article, [Signing and Verifying Messages in Ethereum](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/17/signing-and-verifying-messages-in-ethereum/), where it says that you can pay for other user's gas transactions but so far I haven't seen any implementation or tutorial on how to use it on a Dapp.

My primary use of this smart contract is to **pay transaction fees with my address for the user** in my Dapp. Is there an example of how to use the smart contract for a dapp?

**Example:** A simple ethereum dapp that writes a text on the blockchain but the creator of the contract pays for the transaction fees for a user that owns 0 ETH.

I really hope this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can just write the messages to the blockchain on the backend using your private key.

If you need to be able to prove a given account wrote the message, have the user sign it first with their account's private key.

Comment: The signed message could be the data that I write to the blockchain right? (A string, uint, array) Also when the user gives me the signed message, do I pay for the gas automatically or I still have to approve it?

Comment: The signed message is just a bunch of bytes. You'll pay for gas if/when you make a transaction.